# How to get rid of CORS errors in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

I'm having trouble with CORS errors while fetching data from the https://www.myapifilms.com API. I don't want to use 3th party sites like cors-anywhere or browser extensions. How can I fetch the data without any cors errors? I've tried to add the 'no-cors', 'cors' mode, I also tried with adding the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'. This didn't work either.

Here is the code I use to fetch the data:

```
  const handleData = function(url, callback, method = 'GET', body = null) {
  fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    body: body,
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
  })
    .then(function(response) {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(`Probleem bij de fetch(). Status Code: ${response.status}`);
      } else {
        console.info('Er is een response teruggekomen van de server');
        return response.json();
      }
    })
    .then(function(jsonObject) {
      console.info('json object is aangemaakt');
      console.info('verwerken data');
      callback(jsonObject);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error(`fout bij verwerken json ${error}`);
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

CORS should be enabled from API side not from the UI

You are getting CORS issue because API is not permitting cross origin

So `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` should be configured in the API side.

Methods for adding above configuration varies with language(Node,Java,..etc)

Comment: That's what i thought, so there is no way for me to get the data without using an extension or website?

Comment: @BerendVandenbussche yes